# How should I understand this sentence with the structure: 'not only, but...'?

Tags: sentence-structure

In this following context, according to the structurue 'not only, but (also)', should the subject 'kamma' in preceding part, be the same subject as mentioned one, in following part too?

I think subject of this sentence is different as: 'kamma' is the one subject in preceding part, and while 'our actions, or kamma' is the other in following part.

Sould the subject be only one or the same in this sentence?
Or is it normal?

Context:

> Moreover, kamma is the cause and seed not only for the continuation of
> the life-process after death, i.e. for the so-called rebirth, but
> already in this present life-process our actions, or kamma, may
> produce good and bad results, and exercise a decisive influence on our
> present character and destiny.

Source: P. 21
Fundamentals of Buddhism by Nyanatiloka mahathera

Comment: If you keep the word- Our kamma- in both the case as a subject i don't think it will make any difference.

Comment: Thanks @Sam. I think the phrase 'already in this present life-process' modifies the word 'our kamma', so it would be that 1st kamma refers to all kamma, and 2nd one does present kamma only. if it is without  'already in this present life-process', your idea is ok.

Comment: I think that was the intent, but that sentence is so badly written it's not possible to analyze it seriously.